# Why can't I get 1 gig download from Fios?

Tags: download-speed

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire AXC-603 UB17 (w/ "built-in 10/100/1000 Gigabit ethernet LAN"), w/ cat5e cable from the Verizon modem to my pc.  Verizon installed their fiber optic cable and a G1100 modem, and I have subscribed to their 1 Gig internet speed service.  Using Verizon's speed test, it shows that the download to the **modem** is 900+ Meg for download and upload.  But their speed test indicates that the down load speed to my pc ranges between 200 and 500 meg (upload speed has been as high as 800+ meg).  While talking to Verizon Support, I redirected the cat6 cable that Verizon used between their ONT and modem and connected it directly to the pc, bypassing the modem.  I still got the lower speeds.  I had shut off Ubuntu's Firewall (gufw), unchecked the security boxes in Firefox preferences, and had no other applications running.  Assuming Verizon's speed test "from their network to their modem" is correct, it looks like my pc has an internal limit.
     What should I check/troubleshoot next?  Hardware, software?  TIA.

Comment: This is not really a question about Ubuntu, but I suggest you try testing at several times during the day. If the speed is much better at times when less people use the internet, it's really just Verizon's network which can't handle higher speeds for everyone at the same time… (Most people do a lot less uploading than downloading, so if the network is symmetric up/down, it is normal that more upload capacity is still available.)

Comment: It's almost certainly a result of the test server being slow. Do you get the same results on speedtest.net? Does the connected speed in network settings for your connection show Gigabit? How long have you had the service enabled? It might take some time to finally kick up to full gigabit on the fiber network.

Answer (score 0):

It *most likely* is hardware related. I always get better speeds on Linux Distros versus Windows so I would bet it isn't software base.

For example, my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gets 350 Down 25 Up. My ISP package is 300x20. Windows gets 280x19. Acer R11 Chrome OS gets 80x15 (WiFi only device and has a weak chip). Most onboard LAN and WiFi chipsets are usually very cheaply implemented to help with production costs.

My guess would be to see if you can compile proprietary drivers for your networking chipsets for Acer Aspire AXC-603 UB17 and see if that helps. Though the open-source ones do work very well as seen by my own speed test, or even the proprietary Intel firmware if it is an Intel chip. That way you can rule out software entirely.

Because of the age of the device, I would point the finger at hardware failure from normal "wear and tear." A cheap, more effective solution would be to buy a PCIe ethernet card and/or PCIe WiFi card as a drop in replacement then disable onboard LAN in the bios.

Hope this helps!